# How can I detect the last ajax call in a loop?

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

I have an ajax call inside a loop and I want to detect the last time the ajax call is fired in the loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < diff.length ; i++ ) {

   ...some more code...
   var isLastElement = e == diff.length -1;

     $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        data: {
        },
        url:'somepath',
        success : function (data) {
            if (isLastElement) {
              alert('last item');
            }

        }
      });
 }
```

There is no alert, but also no error in the console.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem. but you may want to use [async/await for ajax](https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax). AFAIK, `isLastElement` would change before the ajax request is completed. Other than that, consider using [`error`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callback to catch ajax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume a typo here, where `e` should be `i`...

```
var isLastElement = e == diff.length -1;
```

But anyway, don't use the loop index. You will save yourself a lot trouble if you use a variable declared outside of the loop... And increment the value of this variable in the ajax callbacks.

```
var callCount = 0

for ( var i = 0; i < diff.length ; i++ ) {

     $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        data: {
        },
        url:'somepath',
        success : function (data) {
        
            if (callCount==diff.length-1) {
              alert('last item');
            }
          
            callCount++
        }
      });
 }
```

Notice that the requests are asynchonous... And it is not garanteed that the responses will be received in order. So the "last" will be the one that took the longuest time...