# Ajax request last response in a loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

Run a loop with the last response received from the previous ajax call. The current code is keep on repeating the same response.

PHP outputs the data in text. Currently, the following code gets response text from the PHP file and appends it to textarea, but only the same data append once.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var query   = "<?php echo $query; ?>";
        var engine  = "<?php echo $engine; ?>";

        function fetchdata(){
            var response = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {
                "query" : query,
                "engine" : engine
            },
            async: false
            }).responseText;
            console.log(response);
            $("textarea").val(response);
        }

        setInterval(fetchdata,5000);
        console.log(fetchdata);

});
```

following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65412271/2477599
but couldn't make it work.

the code is supposed to get a response from PHP file. By using ajax I can get the data in a textarea. The input `query` and `engine` are in string data type. which is entered by the user themself. From the received response, the last element (or text) should be requested again to the Ajax call indefinitely, until stopped by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you want but you could try something like this:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="textarea"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {

            var query   = 1;
            var engine  = 2;

            function fetchdata(query, engine){
                var response = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "search.php",
                data: {
                    "query" : query,
                    "engine" : engine
                },
                async: false
                }).responseText;

                console.log(response);

                $("#textarea").text(response);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    fetchdata(query, parseInt(response)+1)
                }, 5000);
            }

            fetchdata(query, engine);



    }); 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['engine'];
?>
```

Its gone add number from previous call but you can do everything with it.

Comment: Thanks monter, actually the code is supposed to get a response from PHP file. By using ajax i can get the data in a textarea. The input `query` and `engine` are in string data type. which is entered by the user themself.  From the received response, last element (or text) should be requested again to the Ajax call indefinitely, until stopped by the user.

Comment: shouldn't the recusrive fetchData be inside the success of the ajax request, as he wants the recieved response to be sent?